# Issue with getBoundingClientRect in contenteditable div when caret is inside an empty child div

Tags: javascript, range, contenteditable, caret, getselection

I have a contenteditable div with a selectionchange event that logs the new range's getBoundingClientRect. Everything works well until the caret is moved inside an empty div, like this:

```
 <div contenteditable="">
        bbackground: transparent !important;
        <div id="meyes" style="padding-left: 100; min-height:1em;width: 500px;background-color: bisque;text-align: center;"></div>
        text
    </div>

  document.addEventListener('selectionchange', (e) => {
        let sel = window.getSelection();
        if (sel.rangeCount > 0) {
            let range = sel.getRangeAt(0).cloneRange();
            const rect = range.getBoundingClientRect();
            console.log("rect", rect);
        }
});
```

In this scenario, when the caret is inside the empty div with id 'meyes,' the getBoundingClientRect returns all zeros: {x: 0, y: 0, width: 0, height: 0}. Is there a way to resolve this issue or work around it to obtain the actual getBoundingClientRect even in an empty div?"

Any alternative suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You are getting this because your selection is empty. Were you expecting this to respond the size of the full element, even though no text in it is selected?

```js
setTimeout(function() {
  var r = document.querySelector("div").getBoundingClientRect();
  console.log(JSON.stringify(r));
  var r2 = window.getSelection().getRangeAt(0).getBoundingClientRect();
  console.log(JSON.stringify(r2));

}, 3000);
```

```css
div {
  width: 300px;
  min-height: 30px;
  background: orange;
}
```

```html
<div contenteditable="true">
</div>
```